# What are T-junctions in the Speeded-Up Robust Features paper

Tags: image-processing, face-recognition, surf

In the paper entitled "*Speeded-Up Robust Features (SURF)*" **Bay et. al.** mention that

> ... ‘interest points’ are selected at
>   distinctive locations in the image,
>   such as corners, blobs, and
>   T-junctions.

**Can someone explain to me what they mean by T-junctions?**

Note: I'm using the SURF algorithm provided by OpenCV.

I'm not sure if this is the best place to ask this kind of question, but I could not find a better one.

Thanks in advance

**Reference**:

*Bay, Herbert, et al. "Speeded-up robust features (SURF)." Computer vision and image understanding 110.3 (2008): 346-359.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually pretty simple. It's a feature that looks like a T. Think of a street T-junction.

For example one edge that touches another edge perpendicularly.